# How to configure content roots and package prefix in Android Studio

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I would like to create a Android Library from an existing project. But this project uses package names which don't correspond to folder structure

Does Android Studio have something like IntelliJ Idea's [Content Root configuration](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/configuring-content-roots.html)?

Or perhaps Gradle can do something similar?

Answer (score 0):

in gradle you can configure it, and AndroidStudio will sync with gradle.

inside the `android` tag you can use `sourceSets`. Below an example:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['res']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['aidl']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['rs']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
    }
}
```

for more info on sourceSets, you can check the official docs: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Sourcesets-and-Dependencies

Comment: ok I could set up project's roots.
Does it possible to set up package names?
e.g. 
my file is here $PROJECT_DIR/src/java/system/sound/midi/Keyboard.java
I would like this file to be in "my.project" package instead of "system.sound.midi".
Not sure if it possible to do with Gradle.

Comment: I don't think it's possible, but I'm no expert in gradle, it could be worth research more. When I need package names I use them the traditional way.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up your project in Idea then go and open it in Android Studio.
The project structure will be kept and you will be able to edit it right from AS